# Comparing the id of two views in android?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 image buttons in my Android project. I have set some images for the buttons and I change those images in the program. I want to check if the two image buttons have the same images, how can I check that??

I tried directly comparing them in an if statement by getting the two ids  using getId(), but my program stops responding...

Answer (score 2):

you can try to check the `Source` of the `ImageView`, if it is same.
you can not do it directly, as there is no method provided by default. but you can try something like this using `Tag`

in `onCreate():`

```
imageView0 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView0);
imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

imageView0.setTag(R.drawable.one);
imageView1.setTag(R.drawable.two);

//you can create a simple function to get the drawable id:
private int getDrawableId(ImageView iv) {
    return (Integer) iv.getTag();
}
```

this is assuming that same images are picked up from same location. if you have same images being picked up from different locations, then you want to compare Bitmaps.